# Deploy a Hyperledger Fabric Model without command line

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have followed the [Hyperledger tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html) which shows you how to deploy a Hyperledger model using the command line. But Is there any other way to deploy a Hyperledger Fabric Model using a rest service (and generate the composer-rest-service), so I can deploy it from a webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy a business network archive using either the `composer` CLI command or the `AdminConnection` JavaScript API:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/jsdoc/module-composer-admin.AdminConnection.html

Once your network is deployed (using either method) the `composer-rest-server` can connect to it and can generate a REST API automatically.

Comment: Ok, thank you...I want to make a deploy of my model created in my web java aplication so the only way is to clone the composer proyect and make a rest to do that...